# Any benefits to importing sub modules directly (seems to be slower)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, benchmarking

I wanted to see which is faster:

```
import numpy as np
np.sqrt(4)
```

-or-

```
from numpy import sqrt
sqrt(4)
```

Here is the code I used to find the average time to run each.

```
def main():
   import gen_funs as gf
   from time import perf_counter_ns
   t = 0
   N = 40
   for j in range(N):
      tic = perf_counter_ns()
      for i in range(100000):
         imp2()  # I ran the code with this then with imp1()

      toc = perf_counter_ns()
      t += (toc - tic)
   t /= N
   time = gf.ns2hms(t) # Converts ns to readable object
   print("Ave. time to run: {:d}h {:d}m {:d}s {:d}ms" .
        format(time.hours, time.minutes, time.seconds, time.milliseconds))

def imp1():
   import numpy as np
   np.sqrt(4)
   return

def imp2():
   from numpy import sqrt
   sqrt(4)
   return

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

When I `import numpy as np` then call `np.sqrt(4)`, I get an average time of about **229ms** (time to run the loop 10**4 times).

When I run `from numpy import sqrt` then call `sqrt(4)`, I get an average time of about **332ms**.

Since there is such a difference in time to run, **what is the benefit to running `from numpy import sqrt`?** Is there a memory benefit or some other reason why I would do this?

Comment: One thing is the difference between needing to type `np.sqrt(4)` vs `sqrt(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried timing with the `time` bash command. I got 215ms for importing numpy and running `sqrt(4)` and 193ms for importing sqrt from numpy with the same command. The difference is negligible, honestly.

However, if you don't need a certain aspect of a module, importing it is not encouraged.

In this particular case, since there is no discernable performance benefit and because there are few situations in which you would import just `numpy.sqrt` (`math.sqrt` is ~4x faster. The extra features `numpy.sqrt` offers would only be useable if you have `numpy` data, which would require you to import the entire module, of course).

There might be a rare scenario in which you don't need all of `numpy` but still need `numpy.sqrt`, e.g. using `pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()` and manipulating the data in some ways, but honestly I don't feel the 20ms of speed is worth anything in the real world. Especially since you saw *worse* performance with importing just `numpy.sqrt`.